# Color of status bar using react navigation

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I use React Navigation and I need to set the background color of the status bar darker than header. But Android Emulator has already done this automatically, when my phone set bgColor: **none**.

If I use component StatusBar with attribute bg, I wont change bg(**but I can change barStyle-_-**)

[image: Screen of my phone]

[image: Screen of Anroid Emulator]

Comment: Please clearly tell, what you want to do?

Comment: androidStatusBarColor="your hex colour"

Comment: I want that statusBar bgColor change automatically as android emulator

Answer (score 0):

Use this one to change the background color of status bar in react native app

```
<StatusBar barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor="#1D6D91" />
```

Comment: It changes only barStyle, but bg of statusBar stay as bg header